# fill drop down list from database in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

please any idea for fill combo list from database ??

I want to fill the drop down list from table database thanks for help me.

in controller , model  and view

Comment: example for code source

Comment: There is a blog tutorial which shows how to do this as part of the Cakephp cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cakePhp. Here is an example:

HTML (`index.ctp`):

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach($data as $myData): ?>
   <li><?php echo $myData['ModelName']['dataColunm']; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Model:

```
class ModelName extends AppModel{

}
```

Controller:

```
class ControllerName extends AppController{

public $uses = array('ModelName');

//Index.ctp
public function index(){
  $getData = $this->ModelName->find('all');
  //You can add other query parameters 

  $this->set('data', $getData);
  // You use "data" in view (index.ctp)

}

}
```

Comment: thank you Michel but I want how I fill drop down list from a database

Comment: Of course, this is how you fill it from database. If you find it difficult, put your code here. Your DB table structure, HTML, Controller and Model. I will help.

Comment: I have a tabel  Expenses and Markets  in model market: `var $belongsTo = array(
    'Expense' => array(
     'className' => 'Expense',
    )
 );`

Comment: in model expenses: `var $hasMany = array(
   'Market' => array(
   'className' => 'Market',
   'dependent'=> true,
    )
 );`

Comment: in controller ExpenseController: `public function admin_add() {

  $this->set('title_for_layout', __('إضافة صفقة'));
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $expense = $this->Expense->save($this->request->data);
        if (!empty($expense)) {
           $this->request->data['Market']['expense_id'] = $this->Expense->id;
            $this->Expense->Market->save($this->request->data);
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin_index'));
        }
    }}`

Comment: in view :  `<?php $this->extend('/Common/admin_edit'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Expense');?>
<fieldset>
<?php
 echo $this->Form->input('id');
 echo $this->Form->input('season');
 echo $this->Form->input('Paragraph');
 echo $this->Form->input('Subparagraph');
 echo $this->Form->input('designation');
 echo $this->Form->input('montant');
 echo $this->Form->input('expense_id');
?>
</fieldset>

<div class="buttons">
<?php
 echo $this->Form->end(__('Save'));
 echo $this->Html->link(__('Cancel'), array(
  'action' => 'index',
 ), array(
  'class' => 'cancel',
 ));
?>
</div>`